# Is there any way to generate the same key for the "same" widget in Flutter without having any values to be based on

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget which can have multiple input sections from the same type. When I delete the first child then it behaves weirdly like showing still the old value from that first widget. I figured out I need to use keys for the children but then my UX gets broken. Let me show you some code snippet, please:

```
class _ParentState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: stateList
        .mapIndexed((index, element) => ChildWidget(key: UniqueKey(), input: element, onChanged: (text) {
          setState(() {
            stateList[index].text = text;
          });
        }))
        .toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class _ChildState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  final ctrl = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ctrl.text = widget.input.text;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: ctrl,
          onChanged: (value) {
            widget.onChanged(value);
          }
        ),
        ...
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

When I wrote the user experience is broken, I was meaning that whenever the user starts to type into the text field then the focus gets loosen character-by-character since the callback is invoked and then generates a new child widget from the state because it has now "different" key... How can I refactor this? I just need a key mechanism which results the same for a child while it is not disposed yet!?

Comment: I solved the phenomenon by adding an artifical key property to the model (elements in the stateList) so now we can identify which widget neets to be moved

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
Solution:

- remove key
  by default, flutter is smart enough to determine which widget is need to rebuild or not. Thats why, `key` is very rarely used.

```
ChildWidget(input: element, 
     onChanged: (text) {
          setState(() {
          ....
```

When you set `UniquieKey()` you widget will have different key every time build method called.
which is: everytime you call `SetState()` your apps will build NEW widget.

- if you want to set key, you can use index value

```
ChildWidget(
     key: ValueKey('$index'),
     input: element, 
     onChanged: (text) {
```

- what caused your "user experience broken".
  it because, in your `onChange` function, you call `setState()` and also you set `UniqueKey` to your widget. So.. when `setState()` has called, it will re-execute `build` method, and since your `ChildWidget` has Unique key, it will rebuild the widget.

every time user typing, `ChildWidget` is rebuild. that caused lost focus

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply, I appreciate it! I think I know how key works in Flutter but your first two bullet points do act the same, so whenever I delete the first child then the new *first* TextField will still have the same value because Flutter re-use the widgets and disposes the second widget, but the first widget's key has remained the same... (when I have 2 elements and I remove the first then in the new list the first element will have the same 0th index and it should be the second widget's key)

Comment: I completely understand your 3rd bullet point, that is why I was asking whether how I can refactor this because I think I might be doing something wrong fundamentally!?